# AND operation for textfiles in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've 3 `.txt` files. I want to perform `and` operation to these 3 text files and to save the output in a new text file.

```
fid = fopen(AND('a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'));
```

will this work as per my requirements? but i want to save in a new text file, how can i go for it?

For example my `a.txt` file contents are

```
DSC01605.bmp
Hampi8.bmp
DSC01633.bmp
DSC01198.bmp
DSC01619.bmp
```

similarly some images are present in `b.txt` file, and hence in `c.txt` file. I just want to get similar image names out of those files which are saved in above text files, and want to save in a separate new text file.

Comment: I don't understand your question... Do you want to take a logical and on the contents of these 3 files? What do the files look like?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by 'and'. Do you mean concatenate (join end-to-end)?

Comment: what do you mean with "similar image names which is stored in those 3 text files". would you edit your question, including a short practical example of what you wanna achieve?